# MVVMCross Get SelectedItem from a MvxBindableListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, viewmodel, mvvmcross

Little problem with my Android application and I don't know how to solve it with MVVM Cross.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class AddressesShowViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public AddressesShowViewModel(string addressesForListView)
    {
        Addresses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Address>>(addressesForListView);
    }

    public IMvxCommand ShowItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            //return new MvxRelayCommand<Type>((type) => this.RequestNavigate(type));
            return new MvxRelayCommand(DoShowContact);
        }
    }

    private Address selectedItem;
    public Address SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set { selectedItem = value; FirePropertyChanged(() => SelectedItem); }
    }

    private void DoShowContact()
    {
        RequestNavigate<AddressShowViewModel>();
    }
}
```

My AddressesShow.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/INMobileCRM4Android.INMobileCRM4Android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Mvx.MvxBindableListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Addresses'},'ItemClick':{'Path':'ShowItemCommand'}, 'SelectedItem':{'Path':'SelectedItem'}}"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/addresslistitem"
  />
</FrameLayout>
```

I would like to know, how I can get the SelectedItem from the ListView in `AddressesShow.axml`.. I tried to create a Property 'SelectedItem'.. But its getting called at the beginning, when the ViewModel is created (and is obviously returning null), not when the Item is clicked.. Its btw a type of Address, not just a String or something.. Maybe any suggestions?

Comment: Just a guess - I suspect your next question will be about how to pass parameters in the navigation between viewmodels - in which case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192505/passing-on-variables-from-viewmodel-to-another-view-mvvmcross?rq=1 may help :)

Comment: I already solved it before, to pass parameters :) Anyway thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of `SelectedItem` in Droid was identified as an issue last week during preparation for Daniel's talk at Build.

To workaround it, there were a couple of quick answers:

1 There is `SelectedItemPosition` you can use for binding - this is an `int`

2 You can use a `Click` `ICommand/IMvxCommand` binding instead of using `SelectedItem` - in your example, this would be the same axml but

```
public IMvxCommand ShowItemCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxRelayCommand<Address>(address => DoShowContact(address));
    }
}
```

**To be clear** this `Click` option above is what I would use.

---

If SelectedItem really is needed...

Then for a complete answer, Daniel and I prototyped a new binding. This binding was registered using:

```
        registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<MvxBindableListView>("SelectedItem", adapterView => new MvxAdapterViewSelectedItemTargetBinding(adapterView)));
```

and contained the logic:

```
using System;
using Android.Widget;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Interfaces;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.Platform.Diagnostics;

namespace Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Target
{
#warning This needs to be redone for all adapterviews not just list view!
#warning The use of ItemClick instead of ItemSelected needs to be reinvestigated here!
    public class MvxAdapterViewSelectedItemTargetBinding : MvxBaseAndroidTargetBinding
    {
        private readonly MvxBindableListView _view;
        private object _currentValue;

        public MvxAdapterViewSelectedItemTargetBinding(MvxBindableListView view)
        {
            _view = view;
            ((ListView)_view).ItemClick += OnItemClick;
        }

        private void OnItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs itemClickEventArgs)
        {
            var container = (_view.GetItemAtPosition(itemClickEventArgs.Position) as MvxJavaContainer);
            if (container == null)
            {
                MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Warning, "Missing MvxJavaContainer in MvxAdapterViewSelectedItemTargetBinding");
                return;
            }
            var newValue = container.Object;
            if (!newValue.Equals(_currentValue))
            {
                _currentValue = newValue;
                FireValueChanged(newValue);
            }
        }

        public override void SetValue(object value)
        {
#warning Sort out Equals test here
            if (value != null && value != _currentValue)
            {
                var index = _view.Adapter.GetPosition(value);
                if (index < 0)
                {
                    MvxBindingTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Warning, "Value not found for spinner {0}", value.ToString());
                    return;
                }
                _currentValue = value;
                _view.SetSelection(index);
            }
        }

        public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
        {
            get { return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay; }
        }

        public override Type TargetType
        {
            get { return typeof(object); }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                ((ListView)_view).ItemClick -= OnItemClick;
            }
            base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        }
    }
}
```

---

To test this worked, I used the Tutorial PullToRefresh code adapted using:

```
<Mvx.MvxBindableListView         android:id="@android:id/list"         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Emails'},'ItemClick':{'Path':'ShowItemCommand'},'SelectedItem':{'Path':'TheSelectedEmail'}}"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_email"
/>
```

and:

```
    public class SimpleEmail
    {
        public string From { get; set; }    
        public string Header { get; set; }    
        public string Message { get; set; }    
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SimpleEmail> _emails;
    public ObservableCollection<SimpleEmail> Emails
    {
        get { return _emails; }
        private set { _emails = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Emails); }
    }

    private SimpleEmail _email;
    public SimpleEmail TheSelectedEmail
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            MvxTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "HELLO {0} ", value == null ? "null" : value.From);
        }
    }
```

---

One thing to be careful about in all this work is that a listview selected item in Android is slightly different to a listbox selected item in Silverlight/wp - e.g. it can be quite hard to get a listview in android to highlight the current selection and it can be quite hard to get the listview to generate selection changed events.

---

Note: I've logged an issue on Droid SelectedItem to https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/52 - I'll make sure the binding is added to the core library in the near future

Comment: How are you binding to the SelectedItemPosition?  My axml looks like this:  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Agencies; ItemClick SelectAgencyCmd; SelectedItemPosition SelectedItemIndex " but the SelectedItemIndex in my view model is always returning 0;