# ViewModel's constructor is being called again on navigation, and so messenger subscriptions are being subscribed again

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I am building a cross-platform mobile application using `MvvmCross` framework.

Since I would like to share information between ViewModels, I am registering notifications inside the ViewModel's constructor, using the built in `MvxMessenger`. 
Let's assume a message named `ShowAdsMsg`, and then the ViewModel looks as follows:

```
public class AdsViewModel : BaseLookersViewModel, IAdsViewModel
{
    private MvxSubscriptionToken _showAdsMsgToken;

    public AdsViewModel()
    {
        _showAdsMsgToken = MvxMessenger.Subscribe<ShowAdsMsg>(message => onShowAdsNavigation(), MvxReference.Weak);
        MyMessenger.PublishLastMessage();
    }
    private void onShowAdsNavigation()
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

About the `MyMessenger` thing: 
The actual navigation to the ViewModel is performed from `MainViewModel`. 
Since that at the very moment of the navigation itself the `AdsViewModel` does not exist yet, messages published from the `MainViewModel` cannot reach it. 
So, my idea was to naively "remember" the message and publish it when the new ViewModel is ready.
So now the navigation call from the `MainViewModel` looks like that:

```
    private void navigate()
    {
        MyMessenger.RememberMessage(new ShowAdsMsg(this));
        ShowViewModel<AdsViewModel>( );
    }
```

I am now able to navigate to the ViewModel, and all the notifications are successfully caught.

However... 
When I press the BACK button on the device and re-navigate to the same ViewModel, 
The constructor is being called again, and so the message subscription re-occur. 
As a result, when a message arrives the `onShowAdsNavigation()` handler is being fired twice!

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961664/viewmodel-lifecycle-when-does-it-get-disposed) similar post, discussing the question of how to properly dispose a ViewModel, 
but it does not contain a direct solution to my problem.

What I need is a solution. It can be either one of the following:

1. Idea how Not to subscribe to messages on the ViewModel's ctor.
2. Guidance about how and when to correctly dispose the ViewModel.
3. Explanation on why the constructor is being called again, and how to avoid that.
4. A complete different approach to ViewModel information messaging.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Edit:
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723078/mvvmcross-does-showviewmodel-always-construct-new-instances) SO Answer, which basically answers item number 3 in the list above.
Still, I am wondering what approach should I take regarding the messenger issue.

Another Edit:
I verified that the same behavior exists with MvvmCross tutorial [N-05-MultiPage](https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-05-MultiPage). I simply added a ctor to SecondViewModel, and I hit a breakpoint inside it after each BACK+Renavigate.

Comment: Anyone? somebody must have dealt with this before....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Explanation on why the constructor is being called again, and how to avoid that.

The `ctor` is not called twice on the same object - instead what might happen is that a new `View` and a new `ViewModel` are created each time.

By default I **would** expect a new ViewModel to be created on every forwards navigation on every platform.

By default I **would **not** expect this to happen during a back button on WindowsPhone - it doesn't happen here for my test cases - but it could happen if:

- WindowsPhone removes your first Page (and it's ViewModel) from memory - I guess this might happen if your app is tombstoned or if you are using a custom RootFrame - but I don't expect this to happen by default.
- you somehow null the ViewModel (DataContext) in your first Page

Without seeing more of your code I can't guess any more about why this might happen.

---

I'd personally recommend you look deeper at why you are seeing new ViewModels created during Back, but if you just want a quick fix, then you could look at overriding the ViewModelLocator within MvvmCross - see [MvvmCross: Does ShowViewModel always construct new instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723078/mvvmcross-does-showviewmodel-always-construct-new-instances/16723459#16723459)

---

Note that on WindowsStore, I would expect this to happen - WindowsStore doesn't hold Pages from the backstack in memory by default - but you can overriding this by setting `NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;` if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Stuart! I am not facing tomb-stoning nor using a custom RootFrame. Also, I am not doing anything fancy such as nulling my ViewModel. Actually, I verified that the same behavior  exists with your tutorial named `N-05-MultiPage`. I simply added a `ctor` to `SecondViewModel`, and I hit a breakpoint inside it after each BACK+Renavigate. Now, I don't mind recreating View+ViewModel each navigation, but I do want to make sure that I get a consistent cross-platform behavior. Do you have any suggestions for me? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about getting a navigate on the first view model? or on the second? If its on the first, then I would not expect that - that's what my answer was about. If it's on the second, then yes, you are doing a new navigation to a new page so of course you get a new view and a new viewmodel - and that will give you "consistent cross-platform behavior"

Comment: I am trying my best to understand your answers, please bear with me :). I am talking about this scenario:  1. from first view model call `ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>()`. 2. now call `ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>()` (or hit the back button, doesn't matter). 3. now call `ShowViewModel<SecondViewModel>()`.  In each of the three steps above, the `ctor` is being called. So are you saying that this is the expected behavior?

Comment: and if it is, how and when would you recommend me to do `Subscribe` to the messenger events?

Comment: if you need to pass a parameter during a navigation, you don't have to use a messenger - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Navigation or http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/n5-some-first-icommands-and-multiple.html, http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/v3-new-viewmodel-lifecycle.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658913/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-objects-to-navigated-to-viewmodel-in-mvvmcross or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192505/passing-on-variables-from-viewmodel-to-another-view-mvvmcross/ (RequestNavigate has been replaced by ShowViewModel)

Comment: I also don't see the same behaviour as you - if in step 2 you hit Back then this should not cause a new FirstViewModel to be constructed. I honestly think what you need to understand is when WP creates a new Page. Whenever a new page is created then a new ViewModel will be located - and by default this will cause a new ViewModel to be constructed.

Comment: That is true, and indeed I can use navigation parameters for VM to VM communication. I will change my code properly. However, I now no longer see any reason/possibility to `Subscribe` to messenger events inside a VM, as long as I can't `Unsubsribe` on VM deletion, or could I?

Comment: Sorry - the questions in comments are making no sense to me now... maybe try a new simple question with code **just on this point** (whatever it is!) - I will **try** to understand.